# Distriqt Share Native Extension not working with Bitmapdata on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, share, distriqt

I want to share an image on social media. [The extension](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Share) works fine with plain text, but when it comes to sharing with bitmapData property, nothing happens (no errors, no prompts, nothing at all).

I've tried the sample project provided in the repository but I get the same result.

I've also found that if I try sharing a file using *Share.service.shareFile()* it gives me an error:

> share:failed::shareFile::Could not access file. Check
> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and FileProvider

Edit: Working on the sample test project,

the manifest additions are as follows (air. included in the package name as it supposed to be).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            
<application>

    <provider
        android:name="com.distriqt.extension.share.content.ShareFileProvider"
        android:authorities="air.com.distriqt.test.sharefileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/distriqt_share_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity   android:name="com.distriqt.extension.share.permissions.AuthorisationActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
                
</application>
```

Share extension version: 6.0.56

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Distriqt** ANEs are commercial-grade extensions. Their price also include the right to contact their support in case of any inconveniences such as yours. You should execute that right (and then share the solution here).

Comment: Hi @Organis, yes I've purchased the extension but I'm facing a cruel situation on the part of GitHub. Some countries are banned from private repositories due to US sanctions, and I can not register an issue there.

Comment: VPN or an anonymizer browser extension to conceal your location.

Comment: I tried VPN but failed. My account is blacklisted totally.

Comment: You need to change the authority to match your application id, you have the test id in your code above: android:authorities="air.com.distriqt.test.sharefileprovider"  You need to replace that with your id.

Comment: Hi @Michael, as stated I've switched to the sample test project to make sure everything is set up correctly. The authority is matching with package id.

Comment: Solved by updating the dependency ANEs! androidx.core and distriqt.Core. Hope my other extensions are not affected...

Comment: I had missed replacing APPLICATION_PACKAGE with actual bundle prefixed with "air."

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating the dependency ANEs:

```
androidx.core
com.distriqt.Core
```